# Delete all rows below a specific differential value

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, difference

I've got a dataframe df with variabels time, depth, minmax and chla:

```
   datetime          depth    minmax   chla
2014-07-19 07:22:27  15.04    max      7.142671
2014-07-19 07:22:28  15.03     0       6.265014
2014-07-19 07:22:29  15.02     0       7.184299
2014-07-19 07:22:30  15.00     0       6.313580
2014-07-19 07:22:31  14.98     0       6.695170
2014-07-19 07:22:32  14.96     0       5.748133
2014-07-19 07:22:33  14.96    min      6.431526
2014-07-19 07:22:34  14.99     0       6.362146
2014-07-19 07:22:35  14.99     0       7.114919
2014-07-19 07:22:36  14.93    max      7.628331
2014-07-19 07:22:37  14.71     0       5.848734
2014-07-19 07:22:38  14.42     0       6.382960
2014-07-19 07:22:39  13.97     0       8.516395
2014-07-19 07:22:40  13.50     0       6.518251
2014-07-19 07:22:40  12.90     0       6.549472
2014-07-19 07:22:42  12.36     0       5.425516
2014-07-19 07:22:43  11.82     0       5.095961
2014-07-19 07:22:44  11.23     0       5.272880
2014-07-19 07:22:45  10.68     0       5.210438
2014-07-19 07:22:46  10.01     0       4.804565
2014-07-19 07:22:47   9.38     0       5.123713
2014-07-19 07:22:48   8.76     0       3.923439
2014-07-19 07:22:49   8.02     0       3.566132
2014-07-19 07:22:50   7.37     0       2.657254
2014-07-19 07:22:51   6.65     0       2.664192
2014-07-19 07:22:52   6.04     0       2.671130
2014-07-19 07:22:52   5.48     0       2.674599
2014-07-19 07:22:53   4.84     0       2.681537
2014-07-19 07:22:54   4.36     0       1.817756
2014-07-19 07:22:55   3.94     0       1.828163
2014-07-19 07:22:56   3.76     0       1.796942
2014-07-19 07:22:57   3.73     0       1.557581
2014-07-19 07:22:58   3.87    min      2.018958
2014-07-19 07:22:59   4.14     0       2.143842
2014-07-19 07:23:00   4.53     0       1.481263
....
```

What I want to do:

remove all rows for which the difference between min and max (and vice versa) < 5. It is important that all the rows between min and max (marked with 0) are retained as soon as the difference >= 5 (is bigger or equal to 5).

It's a big dataframe and this is only an excerpt. But referring to the top in the end it should look like this.

```
datetime              depth   minmax  chla
2014-07-19 07:22:36   14.93   max     7.628331
2014-07-19 07:22:37   14.71     0     5.848734
2014-07-19 07:22:38   14.42     0     6.382960
2014-07-19 07:22:39   13.97     0     8.516395
2014-07-19 07:22:40   13.50     0     6.518251
2014-07-19 07:22:40   12.90     0     6.549472
2014-07-19 07:22:42   12.36     0     5.425516
2014-07-19 07:22:43   11.82     0     5.095961
2014-07-19 07:22:44   11.23     0     5.272880
2014-07-19 07:22:45   10.68     0     5.210438
2014-07-19 07:22:46   10.01     0     4.804565
2014-07-19 07:22:47    9.38     0     5.123713
2014-07-19 07:22:48    8.76     0     3.923439
2014-07-19 07:22:49    8.02     0     3.566132
2014-07-19 07:22:50    7.37     0     2.657254
2014-07-19 07:22:51    6.65     0     2.664192
2014-07-19 07:22:52    6.04     0     2.671130
2014-07-19 07:22:52    5.48     0     2.674599
2014-07-19 07:22:53    4.84     0     2.681537
2014-07-19 07:22:54    4.36     0     1.817756
2014-07-19 07:22:55    3.94     0     1.828163
2014-07-19 07:22:56    3.76     0     1.796942
2014-07-19 07:22:57    3.73     0     1.557581
2014-07-19 07:22:58    3.87    min    2.018958
2014-07-19 07:22:59    4.14     0     2.143842
2014-07-19 07:23:00    4.53     0     1.481263 
...
```

Until know I tried `subset(),` `abs()`.

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description and objective are not perfectly clear to mean so I am making some assumptions...
1. I understand your objective correctly
1a. The example input and desired output you provided exactly matches your goal
1b. More specifically, you wish to remove every row from the occurrence of a `max` to the next occurrence of a `max` provided the the number of rows between any `min` and any `max` is less than 5.
2. There is a `min` for every `max` 
3. They always appear in the same order

Given these assumptions, the following code produces the desired result.

```
minInd = which(df$minmax == 'min')
maxInd = which(df$minmax == 'max')

minToMax = do.call(c,
                    lapply(
                        which( (maxInd[-1] - minInd[-length(minInd)]) < 5 ), 
                        function(x) { 
                            seq(maxInd[x],(maxInd[x+1]-1)) 
                        }   
                    )
                )
maxToMin = do.call(c,
                    lapply(
                        which( (minInd - maxInd) < 5 ), 
                        function(x) { 
                            seq(maxInd[x],(maxInd[x+1]-1)) 
                        }
                    )
                )


final = c(maxToMin,minToMax)

newDf = df[-final,]
```

To break the code down `minInd` and `maxInd` are the indeces of occurances of `min` and `max` in your data.

`which( (minInd - maxInd) < 5 )` tells us where the difference between min and max is less than 5, that is the forward relationship. The backward relationship is captured by `which( (maxInd[-1] - minInd[-length(minInd)]) < 5 )`

These two functions give us the indeces among the index vectors we compare, that is which sets of indeces of your data exhibit the undesired behavior. We call `lapply` on this sequence to create a sequence of the rows which are to be removed from the data frame `df`.

Since `lapply` returns a list of sequences which we want to colapse into one long vector. We execute `do.call(c,resultFromLAPPLY)` which effectively means `c(list[[1]], ... ,list[[length(list)]])`. These vectors are mapped saved as the two variables `maxToMin` and `minToMax`. Finally we combine them into one vector `final`.

Recall that `final` contains indeces of rows we wish to remove from `df` so we save our desired result with `newDf = df[-final,]`

EDIT: Introduced some line breaks to code for readability.